# Docker java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have the following `docker-compose.yaml` file

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:12.1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myuser
      POSTGRES_USER: mypass
    networks:
      myname:
        aliases:
          - localhost
    volumes:
      - /home/user/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  web:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      network: host
    environment:
      JPDA_ADDRESS: 8001
      JPDA_TRANSPORT: dt_socket
    networks:
      - myname
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 80:8080
      - 8001:8001
    volumes:
      - /home/user/data/images:/data/images
networks:
  myname:
    driver: bridge
```

When I start the application I get the following error
`java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres`

**However using DataGrip I can connect to the postgres DB.**
Why can't my application connect to the database?

Comment: What part of the application is trying to connect to the database?  (If you're trying to connect from somewhere in the Dockerfile, it won't work and it's not a best practice.)  You could probably simplify this by removing all of the `networks:` blocks and the `network:` line in the image build; does that improve things at all?

Comment: It's a java web application trying to connect to the database. Locally (MacOS Catalina) everything works fine. Removing the `networks:` blocks does not change anything